# Column chart with sqllite Db values based on Spinner value chnage?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, charts

I am very new to this API.I have knowledge on doing samples with this API.after that my requirement is display the Column graph based on Spinner Values selection .the query table data is coming correctly the problem is not appending the latest values to the chart .

```
   In My App i have one spinner name it as Customer Name:
when i change the spinner-value i am sending the Customer name to input parameter to sqllite and display the graph for that i write the following code.

package com.appulento.salestracking;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.appulento.salestrackingdb.DBAdapter;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.ChartView;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartArea;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartAxis;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartCollection;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartCollection.IChangeListener;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartNamedCollection;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartPalette;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartPoint;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartSeries;
import com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Types.ChartTypes;

public class SalesTrackingByCustomer extends Activity {

    private DBAdapter db;
    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
     private String[] prodctnames;
     private String[] prodctnames1;
     private double[] product_1;
     private double[] product_2;
     public int count;
     public String custid;
     public Sample customerdetails;
     public ChartCollection<String> collection;
     ChartArea area;
     ChartArea area1;

      private SimpleAdapter mSchedule;

     Vector<String> vec_custid=new Vector<String>();
     Vector<String> vec_oldno=new Vector<String>();
     Vector<String> vec_productid=new Vector<String>();
     Vector<String> vec_qty=new Vector<String>();
     private ListView mListView;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bycustomers);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    prodctnames=new String[10];
    product_1=new double[10];

    prodctnames1=new String[10];
    product_2=new double[10];

    db=new DBAdapter(this);

    final ChartView chartView = (ChartView) findViewById(R.id.chartView);

    ChartPalette palette = new ChartPalette(0xffffd7e8);
    chartView.setPalette(palette);
    final ChartSeries product1 = new ChartSeries("P1", ChartTypes.Column);


    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int position=spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            System.out.println("=====ITEM POSITION======"+position);

            final String selected=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            System.out.println("=====IN SELECTED======"+selected);
                    //finish();
            db.open();
            Cursor customer=db.fetchorderCustomername(selected);
            custid=customer.getString(0);
            System.out.println("=====CUSTOMER NAME ID======"+custid);
            Cursor cursor=db.fetchorderDetails(custid);
            count=cursor.getCount();
            System.out.println("=====COUNT======"+count);

            int i=0;
                    while (i<count)
                    {
                        String productid=cursor.getString(1);
                        prodctnames[i]=productid;

                        String qty=cursor.getString(2);
                        product_1[i]=Double.parseDouble(qty);
                        System.out.println("=====PROID======"+prodctnames[i]+"=====QUANTITY======"+product_1[i]);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        i++;

                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                    {
                        ChartPoint point = product1.getPoints().addXY(j, product_1[j]);
                        point.setAxisLabel(prodctnames[j]);
                    }

                    if(position==0)
                    {
                       chartView.refreshDrawableState();

                       chartView.getSeries().add(product1);


                       area = chartView.getAreas().get(0);

                    area.getDefaultXAxis().setLabelsMode(ChartAxis.LabelsMode.SeriesLabels);

                    }
                    if(position==1)
                    {

                       chartView.refreshDrawableState();

                       chartView.getSeries().add(product1);
                        area1 = chartView.getAreas().get(0);

                        area1.getDefaultXAxis().setLabelsMode(ChartAxis.LabelsMode.SeriesLabels);
                    }

                  //area.refresh();
                    db.close();

                            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });



  My problem is at first time Application Launch the graph is Displaying  successfully when i change the Spinner value selection the app got closed and display the  fallowing exception in my log cat:


java.security.InvalidParameterException: This name already presents at com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartNamedCollection.validateName(SourceFile:128 ) at com.artfulbits.aiCharts.Base.ChartNamedCollection.validate

please see once and let me know where i am doing Mistake in my code.The dynamic vlaues is not appending to that chart in the above code.
Thanks in Advance....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to add new area with the same name. I'm not exactly well versed in the API enough, but i'd imagine that the issue comes when you try this line a second time:

```
chartView.getSeries().add(product1);
```

I also noticed that you never used the following:

```
prodctnames1=new String[10];
product_2=new double[10];
```

If i could make a suggestion, perhaps it isn't best to have all your code in a click listener. maybe you can fill your datasets at the beginning and then only show the graphs upon using the spinner. Because if one clicks the spinner more than once, you have to go to the database to get the same information.

Comment: in my need i want send the spinnerselected value input to the data base to featch the information ?

Comment: i understand, but you could rework that to simply toggling what data to show. It cuts down repeated excursions to your database

Comment: i already tried with array list to clear the previous values and i am appending at that time also i am getting the same issue? http://www.artfulbits.com/support/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=389

Comment: i referd this but i am not get the output?

Comment: i'm very sorry but i can't understand you. you either need to make a new `new ChartSeries()` or remove all the previous ones before adding one of the same name

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            
         ChartPoint point = product1.getPoints().addXY(j, product_1[j]);
         point.setAxisLabel(prodctnames[j]);
         product1.reset();
        }

Comment: by this app goes to debug mode ?

Comment: if these values are present before you run them again `.addXY(j, product_1[j]);` you might have issue.